# Is it bad form to omit the variable in a summation equation?

Tags: summation

I would like to add variable "*a*" *n* times. Usually, a summation has the form $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(a_k)$, $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(a+k)$, etc., but I'm asking about a form $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(a)$. According to Wolfram Alpha, this works fine, but is it a bad practice?

Comment: Yes, you can write that, but what keeps you from writing $a(n+1)$?!

Comment: @adjan Homework. I just (re)learned summations and products and my instructor wants us to write everything in "proper" notation. I can probably do it simply, but it's hard to read an instructor's mind...

Comment: If you have to sum a n times then the summation starts with k=1 not 0. OR k=0 to n-1

Comment: @R_D Thanks for the tip. My programmer brain is getting in the way with indices starting at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can write $$\sum_{k=1}^n a$$
since this is a perfectly valid mathematical expression. However, since it's equal to $n\cdot a$, I see no reason why you would use the long way to write this.

Comment: Thanks. I considered this, of course, but this pertains to a homework assignment where we have to write things out in terms of summations and products, and it's difficult to know exactly what an instructor wants!

Comment: @Abluescarab How is $a\cdot n$ not a product?

Comment: @adjan I meant the "product" with the $\prod_{k=0}^{n}$ form.

Comment: @Abluescarab ok, gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a=(n+1)a$. Reason:

Put $b_k:=a$ for $k=0,1,...,n$ and consider  $\sum_{k=0}^{n}b_k$